# how can i refactor a method with retry policy. without using a 3rd party

Tags: java

I wonder how can i refactor this method with retry lambda [not using a 3rd party retry engine].

(somthing like a lambda that gets number of attempts that will passed as parameter into this method and done this same thing in more functional style

```
public static Connection createDbConnection( JobConfiguration jobConfiguration, ArrayList<String> hostsIps ) {

    Connection retConnection = null;

    Properties connectionProperties = new Properties();

    connectionProperties.put( "user", jobConfiguration.getDbConfiguration().getUserName() );
    connectionProperties.put( "password", jobConfiguration.getDbConfiguration().getPassword() );
    connectionProperties.put( "ConnectionLoadBalance", 1 );
    int attempts = 0;
    while ( ++attempts <= hostsIps.size() ) {
        try {
            String connectionString = String.format( "jdbc:vertica://%s:%s/%s",
                    hostsIps.get( attempts - 1),
                    jobConfiguration.getDbConfiguration().getPort(),
                    jobConfiguration.getDbConfiguration().getDbName());

            retConnection = DriverManager.getConnection
                    (
                            connectionString,
                            connectionProperties
                    );
            retConnection.setAutoCommit( false );
            break;
        } catch ( Exception ex ) {
            LOGGER.error( "Failed to connect to node - {}" + hostsIps.get( attempts - 1 ) + ex );
        }
    }
    return retConnection;
}
```

can you help?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main thing that will simplify your code is to extract all the code inside your while loop and put it in a separate method, e.g. "tryConnect". Then you could use a lambda, if desired, as follows:

```
Optional<Connection> retConnection = hostIps.stream().sequential()
    .map(ip -> tryConnect(ip, jobConfiguration, connectionProperties))
    .filter(Objects::nonNull).findFirst();
return retConnection.orElse(null);
```